# How do I prevent a disk partition from being shown in Windows Explorer?

Tags: c, windows, hard-drive

Assuming I have a 100GB drive and I want to put reinstallation software using 1GB. I would like that 1GB to he hidden - not from users but from the OS. Assuming Windows XP and later. Is there a series of API calls I can use to do that? What other techniques are there to 'hide' a portion of a hard drive?

Comment: Your title and description contradict: you say your don't want the drive to be shown in Windows Explorer but then say you don't want it hidden from (only?) the users, and having something hidden in Windows Explorer _only_ hides it from the user. Please clarify what you're asking.

Comment: I was trying to dissuade people from just saying to make it a hidden file

Answer (score 1):

Simply assign the hidden flag to that partition.  [gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) does that quite well.

Alternately change its type to compaq diag.

Comment: Thanks. I'l have to look into this.

Answer (score 0):

From the first google search for "hide a drive in Windows"

**How to hide a drive in Windows XP:**

1. Click Start -> Run type regedit in the box and click OK
2. Navigate to:

   ```
     HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\
     Explorer
   ```
3. From the menu, navigate to Edit -> New -> DWORD Value
4. Name the New Value NoDrives
5. Next, Right click NoDrives and select Modify, now check the Decimal option and under Value Data enter a decimal value for the drive you would like to hide. For example to hide C you would enter 4. See the list below for more values:
         * A=1
         * B=2
         * C=4
         * D=8
         * E=16
         * F=32
         * G=64
         * H=128
         * I=256

Comment: This just hides it from the UI, but you can just type D:\ etc into the addressbar in explorer IIRC

Comment: This doesn;t hide it from the OS, just from being shown. Writing the file using 'echo . > hiddenFile' is still allowed.

Answer (score 0):

If it is GPT style disk, you can change GPT type GUID to OEM GUID. That will make that partition hidden from all the disk tools (Explorer, Disk Mgr etc).